# Button animation fix with HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a basic button made with HTML and CSS that displays a text when hovering over it. I want to correct the animation effect, which is not quite correct.

When the cursor is removed, the animation decreases the size of the button sharply. So maybe it could be completed with a transition effect?

I hope I was clear enough!

```css
.home-button {
  line-height: 100%;
  padding: 5px 40px 5px 5px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 12px;
  position: relative;
}

.home-button span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  opacity: 0;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #454b54;
}

.home-button:hover {
  animation-name: enlarge;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.home-button:hover span {
  animation-name: appear;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.home-button::before {
  margin-right: 5px;
  background-image: url(https://mcusercontent.com/ec104f3d77537e1962ab6441c/images/d7bb4928-a156-4682-9677-d0d5b47c3a21.png);
  background-size: 40px 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  content: "";
}

.home-complement-button {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px #dadce0;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.home-complement-button:focus {
  background-color: #e8f0fb !important;
}

@keyframes appear {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes enlarge {
  from {
    padding-right: 40px;
  }
  to {
    padding-right: 50px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div style="display:flex;user-select:none"><a class="home-button home-complement-button" href="https://esims.one/" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);text-decoration:none"><span>Home</span></a></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use animation for that. Just use transition. This is more smooth.

```css
.home-button {
  line-height: 100%;
  padding: 5px 40px 5px 5px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 12px;
  position: relative;
  transition: 1s;
}

.home-button span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  opacity: 0;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #454b54;
}

.home-button:hover {
  padding-right: 50px;
}

.home-button:hover span {
  transition: opacity 1.5s; /* I added the transition here because I want it to take 0 seconds when come back. */
  opacity: 1;
}

.home-button::before {
  margin-right: 5px;
  background-image: url(https://mcusercontent.com/ec104f3d77537e1962ab6441c/images/d7bb4928-a156-4682-9677-d0d5b47c3a21.png);
  background-size: 40px 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  content: "";
}

.home-complement-button {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px #dadce0;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.home-complement-button:focus {
  background-color: #e8f0fb !important;
}
```

```html
<div style="display:flex;user-select:none"><a class="home-button home-complement-button" href="https://esims.one/" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);text-decoration:none"><span>Home</span></a></div>
```

Comment: Transition is a form of animation, isn't it?

Comment: it is considered, but there is a difference with animation when it back. animation is cut suddenly, the transition is not interrupted.

Comment: That's clear. I have upvoted your answer before pointing out this detail.

Answer (score 3):

From myself I can offer this solution:

```css
.home-button {
  line-height: 100%;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 12px;
  position: relative;
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 40px;
  
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.home-button span {
  top: 20px;
  opacity: 0;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #454b54;
  
  margin: auto;
}

.home-button:hover {
  width: 100px;
}

.home-button:hover span {
  opacity: 1;
  animation-name: text_left;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}

.home-button::before {
  background-image: url(https://mcusercontent.com/ec104f3d77537e1962ab6441c/images/d7bb4928-a156-4682-9677-d0d5b47c3a21.png);
  background-size: 40px 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 40px;
  min-height: 40px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  content: "";
}

.home-complement-button {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px #dadce0;
}

.home-complement-button:focus {
  background-color: #e8f0fb !important;
}

@keyframes text_left {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div style="display:flex;user-select:none"><a class="home-button home-complement-button" href="https://esims.one/" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);text-decoration:none"><span>Home</span></a></div>
```